# Why does VBA keep inserting date in US format?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table that is built using power query, in the table there are 2 blank columns (appointed/Date Appointed). The `Date Appointed` column is formatted by Power query as date only and using Locale (UK format). Even if I go into the formatting on the table column itself it shows and UK date format.

What I am trying to achieve is when I select "yes" from the dropdown in the `Appointed` column, VBA automatically puts today's date in the date appointed column. The code below works perfectly apart from the fact that it continues to insert the date in US format.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim KeyCells As Range

' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will cause an input
'date and time in next 2 cells to the right when active cell is changed.

Set KeyCells = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("VAMP_P1___P2").ListColumns("Appointed").Range

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
    Is Nothing Then
    
    If Target = "Yes" Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    Else
        Dim answer As Integer

        answer = MsgBox("Changing this cell to anything other than 'Yes' will reset any previous appointed date, would you like to proceed?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Message Box Title")
        
        If answer = vbYes Then
          ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).ClearContents
        Else
        End If

    End If
    
    End If

End Sub
```

As you can see from the code above I have even wrapped the date input in a format using the UK date format as a failsafe but still, it appears in US format as shown in the image below. The true date should be today (05/12/2023).

[image]

Any advice on how i fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of using `Format`, just assign the `Date` value directly to the cell's `.Value` - then Excel will use your systemwide formatting settings.

Comment: Also, check that you don't have an explicit formatting config set on those cells...

Comment: Remember ISO 8601: https://xkcd.com/1179/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to get your regional date-format:

```
Sub test()
    Dim dDate As Date
    dDate = Now 'corrected by FunThomas
    Range("A1").Value = dDate '5/12/2023
    Range("A2").Value = Now '5/12/2023
    Debug.Print Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy") '05/12/2023
    'I forgot why VBA converts this to the wrong format when giving it to a cell
    Range("A3").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    Range("A3").Value = dDate '05/12/2023
    Dim sDate As String
    sDate = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy") '05/12/2023 as a String
    Range("A4").Value = sDate '12/05/2023 -> 05/12/2023 is read as 12th of May
End Sub
```

I'm not a huge fan of how my regional formatting drops the leading zeros (and now that I'm redoing it with FunThomas' remark, I'm also getting the time in the cell) so I tend to opt for the A3 variant where you give it the desired numberformat first.

Comment: Why do you use `Format`  when you assign the current date to a date variable? This will first convert the date to a string explicitly and then, implicitly, convert it back to a date. That makes no sense and can cause only issues. Why not simply use `dDate = Now`?

Comment: Right, my bad but might as well just use `.Value= Now` like with A2 at that point, no? Now that you mention Format converting it to a string, that's why VBA to Excel makes it `12/05/2023` instead of `05/12/2023` because the string doesn't maintain the dd/mm indication so VBA reads it as the 12th of may and your regional settings thus change it to `12/05/2023`. Right @FunThomas ?

Comment: I guess that the implicit conversion from a string to a date is depending on the regional settings - but I'm not sure about the exact rules. It's just that I always get nervous if I see an implicit conversion because that's one of the main reasons for programing errors.

Comment: You're completely right, I simply forgot that the Format function *Returns a Variant (String)*